# Cannot get JSON from geocoding API

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a method, that sends city to Google Geocoding API.

Here is this method.

```
public static async Task<string> ChangeDestination(string city_name) 
{
    string result;
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    var client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=");
    var request = new RestRequest(city_name+"&key=***************", Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    var responseData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChangeLocation>(content);

    result = "hey";
    return result;
}
```

In `content` I get Not Found.

[image]

When I try this request from the postman. I get JSON.

Where can be my problem?

Comment: Not familiar with RestClient but you should probably create it with the URL only, i.e. remove ? and add address= to the Request rather than mixing the query string between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `RestClient` takes a `baseUrl` as parameter, and to `RestRequest` you should pass the `resource`:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/");
var request = new RestRequest("maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + city_name + "&key=xxx", 
                              Method.GET);
```

For all HTTP request issues, you might find [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) useful.

Comment: Will try now. Thank's

Comment: Yeah, that helps. Thank's!

Comment: a suggestion: NotFound is usually URL related. You can use a URL builder to build your GET requests https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416363/7927820